# tensorflow probabitily wrong output type

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensor, tensorflow-probability

UP DATE and ANSWER:
My error was using tf.dataset to feed my model like y_hat=model(x_tst)
using numpy array data give me the good type of output and work as supposed

I try to run tensorflow probality, but get stuck on output type problem.
Followinfg this [exemple](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1f2KNIFRT1I7GDI6ZPGpBpyyjp6Kt7n6Z#scrollTo=zLRRNTkJ_VWt) at cell #3, with

```
y_hat=model(x_tst)
```

the y_hat type is:
 `tensorflow_probability.python.layers.internal.distribution_tensor_coercible._TensorCoercible`

my input are dataset type build like that (2 heads model)

```
input_1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)
input_2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(Xphysio)
output = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y)
combined_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(((input_1, input_2), output))
input_dataset = combined_dataset.batch(32)
```

but if I use directly (like in exemple)

```
y_hat=model(x_tst)
```

instead of (who seem work well and produce results):

```
y_hat=model.predict(x_tst)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <BatchDataset element_spec=((TensorSpec(shape=(None, 120, 9), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 24), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
```

If I use model.predict() the next step using tf probability don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly find it,  to use y_hat=model(x_tst) instead of model.predict and get the good type, I need to feed the model with numpy array in lieu of tf.dataset.